# Calculating the minimum radius for a circle of 3D planes

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, trigonometry, unreal-engine4

Say we have `N` number of 3D card-shaped planes circling around a central origin, facing the middle.
To calculate the locations of these planes (relative to origin), we use the following:

```
auto Delta = FMath::DegreesToRadians(360.f) / (float)(N);
for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    auto X = Radius * FMath::Sin(Delta * (float)i);
    auto Y = Radius * FMath::Cos(Delta * (float)i);
    auto Location = FVector(X, Y, 0.f);
    // Spawn plane actor, set it's location, etc...
}
```

This works well. But now, let's say we want to *ONLY* specify `N`, and use it to calculate `Radius` so that the sides of each plane are barely touching, but not colliding. What we need is a way to calculate the minimum radius.

I realize I could just start at some high value, spawn in some actors, check if they are colliding, and if they aren't, then remove all actors and reduce `Radius` by some value and then start again until we hit a collision, but this seems like overkill. There must be a simpler, more mathematical approach.

Any ideas? Here's an image to help visualize what I'm trying to calculate, given *ONLY* `n` (number of sides) and `a` (width of side):

[image]

Note that `n = 6` and `a = 10` are only figurative examples. They could be any non-zero value.

Comment: there must be, can you better explain what X and Y are ? And how wide are the planes ?

Comment: @farbiondriven I'm working in UE4, so they are left-handed, z-up world coordinates. X & Y specifies an X/Y point on a circle around the origin, at a distance of `Radius` from the origin.

Comment: Thanks ! So you want N actors and you want to know the minimum radius from the origin where they can spawn without touching each other. So the last thing you need to know is the width, then it's a simple equation.

Comment: @farbiondriven I can calculate the width of the mesh, but just for example's sake, let's say it's 248 units wide, and we want 30 meshes

Comment: This might help https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/geometry-plane/polygon.php Answer: n = 30, a = 248 m, r = 1179.78 m, R = 1186.28 m, A = 4388790 m2, P = 7440 m, x = 168 °, y = 12 °

Comment: @KillzoneKid I didn't really think about it, but I guess I *am* making a regular polygon with `n` sides of `a` width. But I'm having trouble working out how that data was calculated using only `n` and `a`. Another potential issue is that the X/Y points in my post are the center of the planes/meshes.

Comment: @KillzoneKid Updated question with my MSPaint skills to better illustrate the current scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just divide the polygon into same-size triangles (pizza slices) and calculate the central angle for one of the triangles (`Delta`). Given the length of triangle base (the perimiter side) `a`, use this angle to calculate the height of triangle. The height is equal to the radius.

```
auto radius = a / FMath::Tan(Delta / 2.0);
```

To calculate coordinates for the middle point of each "side" simply use polar coordinates:

[image: Polar Coordinates]

*E.g.*:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    /* ... */
    auto x = radius * FMath::Cos(i * Delta + Delta / 2.0);
    auto y = radius * FMath::Sin(i * Delta + Delta / 2.0);
}
```

Comment: I feel bad about swapping to this answer, especially when both answers are so similar, but yours is actually cleaner & more efficient for my current code.

Comment: @RectangleEquals Don't feel bad, this answer is more UE related and is using engine functions, so it is the right choice.

Answer (score 2):

> @KillzoneKid Updated question with my MSPaint skills to better
>   illustrate the current scenario

So you want to know X and Y where to put your planes? Should be easy when radius is known. Perhaps try something like this if it works (2D but you can adapt it to 3D):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {

    constexpr double PI = 3.141592653589793238;
    double sideWidth = 248;
    int countSides = 6;

    double deltaAngleRads = 2.0 / countSides * PI;
    double minRadius = sideWidth / (2 * std::tan(PI / countSides));

    double rads = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < countSides; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "X=" << minRadius * std::sin(rads) << "\tY=" << minRadius * std::cos(rads) << std::endl;
        rads += deltaAngleRads;
    }

    std::cout << "Min radius: " << minRadius << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/zo0HV1